# How can I create a button to allow a user to publish a new tweet in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, twitter

I've been doing some research as to how I can create a button that allows a user to publish a new tweet with its contents being that of a variable stored in state, but no luck coming up with anything other than embedding current tweets into the site.

Is anyone aware of any packages that can be installed/resources I can use to make this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Literally 2 minutes after creating this thread I found a solution.

For anyone in a similar situation:

https://saurabhnemade.github.io/react-twitter-embed/?path=/story/twitter-share-button--share-button-with-custom-placeholder